# Only changing a single variable in R

Tags: r, subset

I have a dataframe df:

```
Group   Age    Sales
A1234    12    1000
A2312    11    900
B2100    23    2100
...
```

I intend to create a new dataframe through the modification of the Group variable, by only taking the substring of Group. At present, I am able to execute it in 2 steps:

```
dt1<- dt
dt1$Group<- substr(dt$Group,1,2)
```

Is it able to do the above in one single command? I guess the following would get tedious if I have to create and transform many intermediate dataframes along the way.

Comment: `dt1 <- cbind(substr(dt$Group,1,2), dt[,-1])`

Comment: Thanks! but I will lose the name of the Group variable in this way, would there be modifications made to change the name back to group as well?

Comment: Just name it inside the `cbind()`: `dt1 <- cbind(Group=substr(dt$Group,1,2), dt[,-1])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
dt1<-`$<-`(dt,"Group",substr(dt$Group,1,2))
dt1
#  Group Age Sales
#1    A1  12  1000
#2    A2  11   900
#3    B2  23  2100
dt
#  Group Age Sales
#1 A1234  12  1000
#2 A2312  11   900
#3 B2100  23  2100
```

The original table is unchanged and you get the new one with a single line.

Comment: This answer is smarter. Does it require from a specific library?

Comment: Not at all. This is pure `base` R.